# searche distinct table but return all columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to query a table with 3 rows: id, ip and user_id

I want to return only the rows that have unique values of ip and user_id (not itself unique, but unique as a pair) eg:

```
id         ip          user_id
--------------------------------
1          1           2
2          1           2
3          1           2
4          2           5
5          2           5
6          2           8
7          2           8
8          3           10
9          3           11
```

the result must be:

```
id        ip
------------
1         1
4         2
2         8
6         2
8         3
9         3
```

I'm using Oracle database.

Comment: Do you mean sth. like that: `SELECT distinct id, ip FROM your_table`?

Comment: Where you have more than one row, which row do you want, just the first encountered?

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, ip
from the_table
  join (
     select min(id) as min_id
     from the_table
     group by ip, user_id
  ) t on t.min_id = the_table.id
order by id;
```

or:

```
select id, ip
from (
   select id, 
          ip,
          row_number() over (partition by ip_user_id order by id) as rn
   from the_table
) t 
where rn = 1
order by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(id),ip from table
group by ip,user_id
```